Isolate Referenced Package between 2 projects c#
I have one Internal Package (DBAbs) that uses static classes to abstract database operations.
In my solution I have 2 different projects that both use a reference to (DBAbs) but connect to 2 different databases. Im using Nuget to manage the reference.
It works just fine when I only use one or the other but when I attempt to use both it messes up, it appears that they are sharing the same config and I have to set the connection string to the correct database before I can switch between them.
I drew a diagram that outlines what I thought would happen vs what I observed happening.

Is there a way to isolate DBAbs reference between the 2 DB projects or should I just convert DBAbs from using static classes to an actual reference style so that i can create two instances with different config.
I hope i provided enough info, thanks for any help.

Can't you assign different names to different connection strings?

I can, but I was just curious if it was just a config setting that i could turn on to isolate the DBAbs from A and B. If its not that easy, I can update DBAbs I was just trying to avoid it.

"uses static classes to abstract database operations." - that'll almost always end in tears. If you look at most tools which abstract access to the database, the context or repository object is meant to be limited in scope - not a global god object.

That appears to be the lesson I am learning, I've used this project for so many years and it's always seem to be just fine but I've never had to access more than 1 instance of the same database type. The projects I work on are limited to internal programs and its always been real easy to just make a call to the static class to get data but looks like I will have to alter that project to get rid using static classes and swap over to using instances.

It's possible to isolate it, but I dont think this is easier than modifying a config file.

Using static classes (or perhaps 'hardcoded' config access) is a generally bad idea. Thats why we invented "instances" - same code, but different data (e.g. different connection string).
It is possible to use different versions of a packages using the Aliases="Alias1" parameter (perhaps even using the same version???). However if there is a hardcoded access to some config-file/settings - you still will read the same config. So you should have same DbContext instances that receives different config-values and will provide access to different DBs.

There isn't hardcoded, config. The connection string is set in the app.config and it references those settings and upon the first read the application encrypts the value stored in the app.config, I do have a method to read different keys in the config file and it stores that in a static parameter. Thats the root of the problem, my logic looks to see if that parameter has been set or not, once set it doesn't look to the config anymore and uses just that parameter's value.
